# How much energy could be obtained by freezing water?

Tags: energy, water

I know with our current technology energy is required to freeze water.

But if the theories are correct we should be able to freeze water by extracting energy correct?

How much energy could be obtained from 1 liter of water if you were to say bring it from room temperature to it's freezing point?

Comment: It looks like a homework problem in disguise

Comment: Depends entirely on the coldest temperature bath that you have access to, the rest is application of Carnot efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

> How much energy could be obtained from 1 liter of water if you were to say bring it from room temperature to it's freezing point?

In **net** terms, nothing, in fact less than nothing,

Warm water (e.g. room temperature) contains more heat energy (Enthalpy) than cold water but to extract that energy we need to use a [heat engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_engine#Cycles_used_for_refrigeration), which would require more mechanical work input than heat energy obtained.

Similarly, when freezing water, a small amount of [Latent heat of fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_fusion) is released but to extract it we face the same difficulty as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

You extract heat (a form of energy). Heat only flow from a greater temperature to a lower temperature.

If the water does not freeze then the heat is the heat capacity X volume X temperature difference.

Then you need to add in the heat of freezing.